# Библиотека для парсинга pdf в текст (android)

Tags: java, android

Подскажите какую библиотеку можно использовать в Android Studio для парсинга pdf в текст?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6118652/873481

Я использовал itext .jar  - хорошая библиотека. Насчет Android Studio - не знаю, думаю, как и в обычном джава-проекте, можно просто присоединить .jar к проекту...